# Algorithms for regression analysis which can handle large scale datasets

Tags: regression, predictive-models, large-data

I am a CS undergraduate student and for my final project i developed a regression algorithm that is suited for large-scale datasets (i wouldn't say 'Big Data', but still large scale).

For the final results, i'm looking for regression algorithms that are known to successfully work on such large datasets, so i can use them as a baseline for my algorithm.

I dont have limits to some particular proerties of the dataset, so the algorithm should be general.

Does anybody have an idea for regression models i can use?

EDIT:

To clarify: the best thing for me is to find a paper which shows one (or more) regression models, and their performances on large-scale datasets.
If anybody could also point me out to a known public dataset (that is big of course) it will be very helpfull.

Thanks for helping,

Nir

Comment: Nir, it looks like you have created more than one account. If this is the case, you should merge them.

Comment: How can i check if i have another account?

Comment: If you didn't make another one recently, then you probably don't. I thought I saw a recent new account under the name 'nir' rather than 'ni6go' in the last few days, which was asking about a similar topic. It's possible I was mistaken. If you may have made an account in the past, go to the [USERS](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users) page and type a name in the search bar at the top left.

Comment: No, this is my only account :)

Answer (score 2):

The `biglm` package in R is designed for fitting linear models and generalized linear models to very large data sets.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html